# Convert MySQL insert from comma separated to piping

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to insert detail from one table into another in MySQL table. The compatibility differs as the one table accepts commas to separate detail in a column and the other table accepts piping. What PHP code can I use to convert the commas into piping?

Ok guys let me re-phrase. I am doing a data dump from another db to my db, the problem is that the content formats of the two tables aren't compatible, meaning that my one table uses UPPERCASE and the other one uses camelCase, and that the one uses (,) without spaces behind or infront where the other table uses (|) with spaces on both sides. I'm lost and need help

Comment: What particular kind of query you're talking about?

Comment: A normal mysql_query() in PHP

Comment: Are you sure you're using database properly? Whatever details should be stored from the separate table, not in the same field separated by some literal

Comment: What kind of SQL query, not what kind of PHP/SQL interface.

Comment: Ok guys let me re-phrase. I am doing a data dump from another db to my db, the problem is that the content formats of the two tables aren't compatible, meaning that my one table uses UPPERCASE and the other one uses camelCase, and that the one uses (,) without spaces behind or infront where the other table uses (|) with spaces on both sides. I'm lost and need help

Comment: Are you sure you're talking of mysql database? Got examples of all that stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: @Corrie If this is what you looking for please consider accepting my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
$replace =  str_replace(", "," | ", $result2);